# Regex - Найти в тексте все фразы находящиеся между определенными подстроками

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<VAST version="2.0">\n  <Ad>\n    <InLine>\n      <AdSystem>Applift<\/AdSystem>\n      <AdTitle>AppliftRTB<\/AdTitle>\n      <Description>AppliftRTB<\/Description>\n      <Creatives>\n        <Creative>\n          <Linear>\n            <Duration>00:01:16<\/Duration>\n            <VideoClicks>\n              <ClickThrough><![CDATA[http:\/\/my.com]]><\/ClickThrough>\n            <\/VideoClicks>\n            <MediaFiles>\n              <MediaFile delivery="progressive" type="video\/mp4" bitrate="500" width="640" height="360"><![CDATA[http:\/\/fgfg4.ssl.mydomain.net\/content\/65cd1c8b69d2143448d7227d388fa5e39eb--video.mp4]]><\/MediaFile>\n            <\/MediaFiles>\n          <\/Linear>\n        <\/Creative>\n      <\/Creatives>\n    <\/InLine>\n  <\/Ad>\n<\/VAST>
```

Нужно найти например ссылки, их общий критерий в том что они находятся между [CDATA[ и ]]

Comment: А причем тут теги (которые в заголовке) если в тексте сказано искать не между тегами а между обычными словами, как в обычном тексте. И кстати, что вы пытались сделать самостоятельно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, на python:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<=\[CDATA\[).*?(?=]])', 'abc[CDATA[xyz]]----[CDATA[***]]bla-bla') # --> ['xyz', '***']
```

Здесь:

`(?<=\[CDATA\[)` - look-behind, то, что должно предшествовать искомому

`(?=]])` - look-ahead, то, что должно идти после искомого

`.*?` - ищем любые символы, нежадный поиск

В итоге, ищем минимальное кол-во любых символов между look-behind и look-ahead.